# missing libstdc++.so.6.0.19

Tags: software-installation

I installed maldet (LMD) on my kubuntu 14.04 64bit laptop.
I ran the -m switch `maldet -m /tmp,/run/shm,/home`
After a few minutes I rebooted the laptop.

Since then I have had issues.
Cannot do a "apt-get upgrade", gives error:

```
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I looked `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` does exist, but the `libstdc++.so.6.0.19` it points to is missing.

Can I download file somehow?

I can also not get the KDE GUI to load.

Current "runlevel" is --- N 2

Comment: It is impossible that your PC could reboot with missing libstdc++, it is among the most essential things. More likely, you understand something wrong. Try `ldconfig`.

Comment: ldconfig gives no reply.

Comment: it should not. It fixes broken library symlinks.

Comment: Ok. Now the "libstdc++.so.6" file is missing...

Answer (score 0):

Download the following [deb](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libstdc++6_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb) package and install the missing library with

```
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_4.8.2-19ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

It should reinstall the needed files (See the package [filelist](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libstdc++6/filelist))

Comment: Ok, thanks. followed instructions. Files are back and I can run "apt-get" with no errors. Rebooted laptop, GUI still not available.

Comment: @KeshaNesral: Good, now try to reinstall your desktop with apt-get: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Ran command - still no GUI.

Comment: @KeshaNesral May I suggest to create a new question about the missing GUI and close this one? With a title like `unable to start my kubuntu desktop` you'll gather more attention I think